On same computer, Skype works fine on Windows, but distorts sound on Ubuntu
I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Windows 11 laptop (so now I can choose to boot whichever suits me best), and on it I have installed Skype via snap (so it is located at /snap/bin/skype).
When I use Skype on my windows OS everything work perfectly. When I use Skype on my Ubuntu OS however, I can hear my interlocutors fine but they have trouble hearing me correctly - they tell me that the sound is very distorted and when I speak they only hear disjointed unclear syllabes.
Any ideas on how to fix this ?
By the way, I take the extra precaution of closing every other app before using Skype.
Similar (but different) question here, the given answer does not apply to me as this is a pure Ubuntu issue

Does anything change if you remove the snap package and download the .deb package from skype website and install it?

@ArchismanPanigrahi Thx for your feedback. I'll try that and say if it works next time I have a Skype conversation.
